# Cocos2d 2.1 AWTextureFilter blurring only part of texture

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, blur

I use Cocos2d 2.0 and AWTextureFilter. I need to blur texture. Here is my code:

```
//Create mutable texture
CCTexture2DMutable *texture = [[CCTexture2DMutable alloc] initWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"].CGImage resolutionType:kCCResolutionUnknown];

//Apply blur to the mutable texture
[AWTextureFilter blur:texture radius:10 rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, texture.contentSize.width, texture.contentSize.height)];

//Create sprites to show the textures
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture];
sprite.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
[layer addChild:sprite];
```

But in result I get sprite with only part of blurred (screenshot):
http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/182/blura.png

Why so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you'll have to multiple it with content scale factor because the texture content size is in points, not pixels.

```
CGSize size = texture.contentSize;
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 
                         size.width * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR(), 
                         size.height * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR());
[AWTextureFilter blur:texture radius:10 rect:rect];
```